# 2d subarray index google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2D array question in google spreadsheet using app script.

I know to get make the code fastest, I'm supposed to use as few get and set functions as possible. So I'm trying to read a whole sheet into an 2D array first then referencing parts of it. Except I'm not sure how to reference the 2D array once it's in.

Here is what i have done so far.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var COMPANYIOSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var IO_array= COMPANYIOSheet.getRange("A1:c10").getValues();
```

I want to do something like:

```
var subarray=IO_array[3:5][1];
```

but that doesn't work. I can only seem to reference just one point ie:

```
var subarray=IO_array[3][1];
```

How do i slice into a sub 2D array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a complement to Adam's answer, in your example `IO_array[0]` is row 1, `IO_array[1]` is row 2 etc..., each of them being a 1 dimension array.
So the 'rows' are pretty easy to manage.

As for the columns, as Adam suggested you will have to iterate, here is a possible example :

```
var col = new Array()
for(i=0;i<IO_array.length;++i){
  col.push(IO_array[i][0] ;// taking index 0 means I'll get column A of each row and put it in the new array
}
```

hoping both answers will make it clear enough ;)

Comment: wow. so complicated for such an easy action.
what if i wanted to make a sub 3x3 array out of the IO_array? can you help  me with some code on that? Thanks Serge.

Answer (score 5):

> How do i slice into a sub 2D array?

By using [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). ;-)

```
var subarray=IO_array.slice(2, 5);
```

Then you can reference `subarray[i][1]`. If you needed to create a new array with only the "second column", you would need to use some iteration.

---

edit: to add to Serge's addition, and in reply to your comment, here is a general way for returning a 2D sub-array from an array:

```
function slice2d(array, rowIndex, colIndex, numRows, numCols) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = rowIndex; i < (rowIndex + numRows); i++) {
    result.push(array[i].slice(colIndex, colIndex + numCols));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, this is what I'd call a 'positive collaboration' ;-) thanks and +1 for the "complement to complement" !

Comment: This solution works like charme. I copied and pasted it and did exactly what I needed. My scripts running  >100 times faster